# I would like my angular component to accept "directive-like" attributes as Input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have a `<app-my-table></app-my-table>` component that accepts `showActions` as input.

I usually use it like this `<app-my-table [showActions]="true"></app-my-table>`

I would appreciate if I can make it work using this syntax too:

```
<app-my-table showActions></app-my-table>
```

Please see example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-property

Comment: What do you want to achieve using this ? If you are trying to have an input, then you  should have a value to pass as an input, in which case the syntax `[input_key]=value` is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that you can create a new directive and then inject this directive in the constructor of your Component.

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() private showActionsDir: ShowActionsDirective) {
    if (showActionsDir) {
        this.showActions = true;
    }
}
```

Mind the `@Optional` and `@Self` decorators so that angular won't throw an error when the directive isn't found and that it only searches in the local injector of the component.

@trichetriche's answer works as well but it isn't really expressive in my opinion. On the other hand, the way I provided can be looked at as too much unnecessary code and a useless directive because it only is a marker for the component and has no other functionality.

If I were you I would choose the most explicit way available, which you've already shown in the question (`[showActions]="true"`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the suggestion regarding explicit way.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-property-q7lhqc?file=src/app/my-table/my-table.component.ts)

```
private _showActions = null;
public set showActions(value: any) {
  this._showActions = value === '';
  ...
```

To explain a bit :

When you use the `@Input` decorator, you can define a default value to your variables. Here, we will use `null` as the default, although you could just use `undefined`.

When you write your input in your component selector like you want to (`<x showActions>`), you actually write a shorthand. The real syntax is

```
<x showActions="">
```

This means that your input value, when you don't provide one, is the empty string `''`.

This means that all you have to is compare the input value to an empty string, and set your internal variables accordingly.